# Get user created list in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

My goal is to have a user enter an item into a textbox, click "add" and have that item added to a list. The user should enter X amount of items and then click submit. I would then like to use python to manipulate that list of items.

Here's what my HTML template looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Foo </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="input text" id = "items">
                {{ form.item.label }} {{form.item}}

            </div>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" onclick="addItem()">

            <ul id = "itemlist" name = "itemlist">
            </ul>
            <script>
                function addItem(){
                    var ul = document.getElementById("itemlist");
                    var li = document.createElement("li")
                    var children = ul.children.length + 1
                    li.setAttribute("id", "item"+children)
                    var input = item.value;
                    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
                    ul.appendChild(li)

                }
            </script>

            <div class="input submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's what my current Python script looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

class ReusableForm(Form):
    item = TextField('Item:', validators=[validators.required()])



@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.form['itemlist']
        print(content)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The main issue is in my "content = request.form['itemlist']" line. I can't seem to find a good way to pass the list from the html to python when the Submit button is clicked. My later goal will be to scrape specific websites for the items in the list that the user created.

Comment: What is the result when you run `print(content)`?

Comment: I get a Bad Request Error. I've also tried using request.form.get('itemlist'), but that just returns None.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `flask` form has an `item` but not an `itemlist` so it does not recognize your request. You can change this by doing this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.form['item']
        print(content)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

*HOWEVER* this will not work as it will only print the last item in the item list. Because the last thing entered into your `flask` form was the last item in `item` list. Unfortunately I could not figure out a solution to this exact problem as sometimes flask forms have some strange undesirable behavior. However, a `TextAreaForm` accomplishes the same exact thing as you are intending to do if you would like to use that instead:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

class ReusableForm(Form):
    items = TextAreaField('Item:', validators=[validators.required()])

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    form = ReusableForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        items = [x.strip() for x in request.form["items"].split("\r\n") if x != '']
        print(items)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

With the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Foo </title>
    </head>
    <style>
            label.textarea-label { vertical-align: top; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label id="items" class="textarea-label">Items:</label>
                    {{ form.items(placeholder="Items", rows=8) }}
                    {% for error in form.items.errors %}
                         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}<br>
            <div class="input submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that same issue of only being able to get the last item. The TextAreaForm will work great though!

Comment: Would there be a way to append to it without using jQuery? Say that I wanted users to either be able to type items directly into the TextAreaForm (like it currently is) or a different value into a separate textbox that would be passed through a python function and then a new value would be appended to the TextAreaForm. I could try and write some sudo code if that would help.

Comment: @LoganKelly unfortunately I'm not a huge jQuery expert. I use a lot of Flask though. I played around with a couple of things and unfortunately couldn't figure a way it could work. Maybe you could entirely remove the Flask form and just build off an HTML form? That could be your solution considering the `TextForm` is not behaving in a way we like. There is a `form.getlist` function which could be useful